# Null-safety with Reactor and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, kotlin-null-safety

Based on this part of documentation Reactor should support null-safety:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#kotlin-null-safety

Nevertheless, using `map` I am able to easily skip null-checking :

```
internal class NullabilityTest {
    @Test
    fun nullability() {
        val userWithMap: Mono<String> = UserRepo.findUser(5)
            .map { it?.getName() }//this returns String?, it should not compile 
    }
}

class User {
    fun getName() = "Mike"
}

class UserRepo {
    companion object {
        fun findUser(id: Int): Mono<User?> {
            return Mono.empty()
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in this example `String?` is assigned to `Mono<String>`. It would be great to receive a compiler failure in this case.
Is it a bug in reactor or rather something that was never implemented?

I am using:
reactor 3.2.12

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `map` doesn't have annotations on it, and since it is written in Java, `R` is a platform type in the code, so the Kotlin compiler won't complain:

```
    /**
     * Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} by applying a synchronous function to it.
     *
     * <p>
     * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/mapForMono.svg" alt="">
     *
     * @param mapper the synchronous transforming {@link Function}
     * @param <R> the transformed type
     *
     * @return a new {@link Mono}
     */
    public final <R> Mono<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
        if (this instanceof Fuseable) {
            return onAssembly(new MonoMapFuseable<>(this, mapper));
        }
        return onAssembly(new MonoMap<>(this, mapper));
    }
```

Comment: So basically it means, nullability is not handled yet. Thx for information